# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings')

Tags: android, eclipse

So I recently (like today recently) began to try to work in eclipse. I've been following android developers beginners course, and everything went fine until this point. I've gotten to building a simple user interface (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Button) and did EVERYTHING word for word, but when I try to run it it says that

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').

I went back and checked everything, and I did everything as they explained and it still does this? I'm a total noob, so maybe I'm just missing something but I don't know what. I restarted eclipse, and it still wouldn't run the app, and said for the millionth time I have an error.

This is my design sheet:

In layout activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:orientation="horizontal">    
   <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"        
    android:layout_weight="1"        
    android:layout_width="0dp"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />    
    <Button        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

in values
string.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

   <string name="app_name">My First App</string>    
   <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>    
   <string name="button_send">Send</string>    
   <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
   <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
   </resources>
```

and that's ALL I've messed with. I don't see a problem?

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I don't know what you've done, but somewhere in your project you are referencing `@string/action_settings` and haven't shown where.  Do a find then post the resulting XML where it is.

Answer (score 10):

ha - I am doing the tutorial and got the same thing. You copied/pasted the entire `strings.xml` file, but this file is missing a value that the app needs. It's a bug in their tutorial.

Add this line back to strings.xml:

```
<string name="action_settings">something here</string>
```

Where I put "something here" I can't remember what the original text was.

The problem is that main.xml (under res/menu), which of course we didn't touch in the tutorial, references the string "action_settings". This was deleted when you copied / pasted the entire string.xml from their example.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED:

add ..\res\values\strings.xml

```
<string name="action_settings">Action Settings</string>
```

And Update ..\src\com\example\helloworld\MainActivity.java Line 18 with follows

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.**main**, menu);

it worked for me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is that:
 Settings,you can use Settings instead of something here.the error often happened that you deleted the statement in the strings.xml carelessly.
I also got the same thing and solved until I have seen the hint.Thank you very much Kiirani and bigmike

Comment: Yes,I do.I also give the correct answers: add the  <string name="action_settings">Settings</string> to the strings.xml .

Answer (score 0):

This error means a reference is being made about a recource that has yet to be defined. If you keep going with the tutorial, they actually say you will see this error! So keep going and you will learn how to fix it in the sections following.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="action_search">Search</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error but I noticed that in res/values/strings.xml the tag is not start with  `"<"` maybe you have the same mistake

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">android app</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

</resources>
```

my advise is make your project from the scratch