# error: ``Syntax error on token "heading", delete this token'' in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

So I am following a tutorial on how to make a TicTacToeGame.
I got an error the same as this: [No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648745/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-title-with-value-string-ac)
so I added this line in my code:

```
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```

Now I got this new error: ``Syntax error on token "heading", delete this token''.

error is in the class: R.java > R > string.

this line:

```
 public static final class string {
        public static final int =0x7f0a0028; \\red mark @ int
```

I think the error is because I ``settings'' isnt the word I should use, but im not quit sure.

this is my main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.tictactoetest.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

this is my strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">testjk</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="turn_human">Your turn.</string><string name="first_human">You go first.</string>
    <string name="turn_computer">Android\'s turn</string>
    <string name="result_tie">It\'s a tie!</string>
    <string name="result_human_wins">You won!</string>
    <string name="result_android_wins">You lose!</string>
    <string name="one">1</string>
    <string name="two">2</string>
    <string name="three">3</string>
    <string name="four">4</string>
    <string name="five">5</string>
    <string name="six">6</string>
    <string name="seven">7</string>
    <string name="eight">8</string>
    <string name="nine">9</string>
    <string name="info">Info</string>
    <string name="human">Human:  </string>
    <string name="ties">Ties:  </string>
    <string name="android">Android:  </string>
    <string name="contact_heading">Contact Info</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="contact_info">

        <b>Name:</b> hiii
        <b>Achternaam</b> hello
        <b>Email</b> test@haha.com
        </string>
        <string name="about heading"> About </string>
        <string name="">This app allowed you to play a game tic tac toe 
            blablalbalbalblalbalblalbalblablalblablalblalbla</string>


</resources>
```

Comment: What if you renames "action_settings" to "action_settings_title" and will use it when inflating the menu?

Comment: Do you mean I have to change it in the main.xml or the string.xml file? or both? I dont really get it

Comment: Both in the `strings.xml` and `main.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public static final int =0x7f0a0028; \\red mark @ int
```

There's no name here

EG:

```
   public static final int ticTacBlahBlah = 0x7f0a0028;
```

because of

```
    <string name="">This app allowed you to play a game tic tac toe 
        blablalbalbalblalbalblalbalblablalblablalblalbla</string>
```

Put a name in, and things should work.

```
    <string name="ticTacBlahBlah">This app allowed you to play a game tic tac toe 
        blablalbalbalblalbalblalbalblablalblablalblalbla</string>
```

Comment: okay thanks, i changed it to this in the strings.xml file <string name="TicTacToeGame">This app allowed you to play a game tic tac toe 
            blablalba</string> I changed it to this in the main.xml: android:title="@string/TicTacToeGame". But now im getting this error: Syntax error on token "heading", delete this token @ this line in my R.java file public static final int about heading=0x7f0a0026;

Comment: I already see the problem I forgot an underscore by about heading